# Accessing array elements within the array

Tags: php

Basically, I’m working on a shopping cart and trying to make a config file.

I want to include previous elements in the array within other elements (to build paths to different directories) as shown below:

config.php

```
return array(

    /// Database info \\\
    //...

    /// Directory Paths \\\
    'dir_root' => $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . '/mywebsite', //root/mywebsite
    'dir_pub' => this->'dir_root' . '/public_html',//root/mywebsite/public_html

    'dir_res' => this->'dir_pub' . '/res', //root/mywebsite/public_html/res
    'dir_imgs' => this->'dir_res' . '/imgs' //root/mywebsite/public_html/res/imgs

    // and so on...
);
```

I'm not sure how or if its even possible to do this. Any suggestions or better ways of doing this?

Comment: You can't do that. Not without assigning something to a variable first anyway. `this` (well, `$this` actually) is a variable (reference to the current instance) that is only used in objects (classes). read through some documentation on [the official site](http://php.net) to learn the basic syntax

Answer (score 0):

You would have to do something like:

```
$arr = Array( 'dir_root' => $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . '/mywebsite' );
$arr['dir_pub'] = $arr['dir_root'].'/public_html';
$arr['dir_res'] = $arr['dir_pub'].'/res';
$arr['dir_imgs'] = $arr['dir_res'].'/imgs';

return $arr;
```

and ensure the variables are assigned in a sensible order.